# How can I ensure creatures do not infest my farmland?

Tags: starbound

I am trying to farm cotton so that I can make new outfits, but I seem to have a [Gleap](https://starbounder.org/Gleap) infestation.

As you can see by the following image, the extreme hill makes keeping pests away from the farm a bit of a challenge, but I have placed lighting, a gate and made a makeshift gleap pit. Yet they still (Not pictured) seem to just appear by the scarecrow before leaping down to annoy me.

Is there anything more I can do to pest-proof my farm? Note they do not come from the right side as off screen is the start of my house.

[image: A farm with cotton plants is overlooked by a shear cliff, torches lining the edge.]